# uVision Keil STM32 Error on debuging "*** error 57: illegal address (0x08000000)"

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, stm32, keil

I write a simple code that just setup clock and initial conditions for STM32F103RBT6, and program it on my board via ULINK2 successfully.

But while I'm going to debug mode, I see this error :

```
*** error 57: illegal address (0x08000000)
```

Also, I can not set a breakpoint on my program, but disassembly section works for while then trapped in a loop.

note that I have many other programs that I did programming on my board successfully and debugging via this ULINK2, but this simple one take all of my time!

There is some pic form my settings:

**debug mode**

[image: x]

**This is my simple Program**

[image: x]

**Target setting**

[image: x]

**Debug Settings**

[image: x]

[image: x]

[image: x]

Comment: I try all of debug settings in a various manner, even I use CUBEMX to create project again. even test it on both JTAG and SWD too, but no success. I'm hanging!

Answer (score 0):

I just change my ULINK debuger with JLINK V9.3 then all things with same settings goes well

Answer (score 0):

In Debug -> Settings -> Debug, ensure that "Download to Flash" is unticked.

Apparently, it should be disabled by default anyway. It's designed to be used for code running from RAM.